# How to inherit a tkinter GUI window with OOP class?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI which has several windows that should look similar. All windows should have the menu at the left. On the right side, it would have the stuff for which the window is made, so that would vary between the several windows.

A picture to clarify what I'm trying to explain:

[image]

So the menu on the left should stay the same for every window, but the content on the right should vary. The code I'm working with is:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Home:

    def __init__(self, master):
        maincolor = 'darkgrey'
        menucolor = 'grey'

        # Menu creation
        menu = tk.Frame(master, bg=menucolor)

        # Main creation
        main = tk.Frame(master, bg=maincolor)

        # Menu positioning
        menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # Main positioning
        main.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsew')

        # Menu items
        self.home = tk.Button(menu, text='Home')
        self.overview = tk.Button(menu, text='Overview')
        self.apartments = tk.Button(menu, text='Apartments')
        self.students = tk.Button(menu, text='Students')
        self.stats = tk.Button(menu, text='Statistics')

        # Menu items location
        self.home.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(25, 50), padx=15)
        self.overview.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
        self.apartments.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
        self.students.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
        self.stats.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)

        # Menu items configuration
        buttons = [self.home, self.overview, self.apartments, self.students, self.stats]
        for self.button in buttons:
            self.button.configure(width=20, height=5, highlightbackground=menucolor)

        # Main items
        self.maintext = tk.Label(main, text='Welcome to the Apartment Manager', bg=maincolor, pady=250)
        self.maintext.pack()


class Overviews(Home):
    pass


class Apartments(Home):
    pass


class Students(Home):
    pass


class Stats(Home):
    pass


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Apartment Manager')
root.geometry('750x750')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=7)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.wm_withdraw()
root.update()

runit = Home(root)

root.after(1, root.deiconify)
root.mainloop()
```

My question is, how could I inherit from the `Home` class so that everything but the content on the right hand side is the same?

Comment: You should put the `left` window into another class and not included in `Home` class.

Comment: Okay thanks. Why is that better than putting it into the `__init__` of `home`? Should I put anything into the `__init__`, if so, what?

Comment: I think you want to switch the right window whenever one of the buttons on the left window is clicked, right?  So how would you get the instance of, for example, `Overviews` page when the `Overview` button of `Home` is clicked?

Comment: I thought by calling the Overviews class through the button command (on the home screen) and then inheriting both the left and right part and overwriting the right part within the Overviews class. No idea whether that is appropriate or possible though. Would love to hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be inheriting from the "Home" class at all. If you want the buttons to be available for every page on the right, they shouldn't be part of the pages. If you have them in a class and have every page inherit from that class, you'll end up with 25 buttons instead of 5.

Instead, divide your root window into two: a frame on the left for the buttons, a frame on the right for each individual window. You can then either create the buttons in a separate class or separate function. At the end, the class for Home, Overview, etc should all be identical and none of them should have the buttons.

Comment: So I shouldn't create a separate class with the buttons which is being inherited by the other classes? 

What do you mean with 'none of them should have the buttons'? How should they get into my screen then? Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: @Jem: _"So I shouldn't create a separate class with the buttons which is being inherited by the other classes?"_ - correct. You can put them in a class, but the other classes shouldn't inherit from it. Inheritance isn't designed for sharing components. Each class gets its own set of widgets. The buttons get onto the screen by creating them in a separate function or class, or just creating them in the global scope.

Comment: My initial idea was to destroy everything on a button click and creating both the left and right side new. But if I understand you correctly, the left (buttons) should never change as it mustn’t be part of the right side. So only the right would change, depending on what button in the left to is clicked

Answer (score -1):

You should split the commands below into a function. Now after changing a screen you can just call it in new function `self.left_menu()`.

```
    def left_menu(self):
        # Menu items
        self.home = tk.Button(menu, text='Home')
        self.overview = tk.Button(menu, text='Overview')
        self.apartments = tk.Button(menu, text='Apartments')
        self.students = tk.Button(menu, text='Students')
        self.stats = tk.Button(menu, text='Statistics')

        # Menu items location
        self.home.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(25, 50), padx=15)
        self.overview.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
        self.apartments.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
        self.students.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
        self.stats.grid(row=4, column=0, pady=(0, 50), padx=15)
```

If you will be calling it outside of a class you can do that by assigning the class to a variable and then calling the function.

```
obj = Home()
obj.left_menu()
```

Comment: So I should take everything out of the `__init__` function? What should stay in the `__init__`?

Comment: the `__init__` function is not recallable. I suggest putting there variables and functions that you will have to call only once.

Comment: At this point, I don't really know yet which things I'd like to put in the `__init__`, would it be OK to put nothing there?

Comment: @Jem yes. The `__init__` is not a required function to call.

Comment: Alright, yes I will after I incorporated it in my code and if it solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the menu creation and menu positioning also be put in the left menu class?

Comment: @Jem I have missed that, it should be, I am sorry.

Comment: Still trying ;)

Comment: @Jem any success?

Comment: I have put them in a separate class instead of in a function. Still trying to figure out how I can show the next window by clicking on one of the buttons.

Comment: @Jem you have to add argument `command = show_second`  in the `Button` note that there should be no `()`. for example. `        self.stats = tk.Button(menu, text='Statistics', command = main)`